# Get object context from std::function

Tags: c++

I have a `std::function` that points to a class member function, eg, `&Foo:bar`. Does the `std::function` object record the object context, eg, `Foo*`? Is there any way to obtain the context from the `std::function` object/class?

The purpose is to find out if my `unordered_multimap` of functions already contains a function from that *context* (but not necessarily that same class member function).

Example;

```
std::unordered_multimap<int, std::function<int(int)>> callbacks;

Foo* myFoo = new Foo();
callbacks[1].emplace( std::bind(&Foo::bar, myFoo, std::placeholders::_1) );
callbacks[1].emplace( std::bind(&Foo::bar2, myFoo, std::placeholders::_1) ); // now callbacks contains 2 functions for the same object/context. I want to avoid this

// Check context exists before inserting
auto vCallbacks = callbacks.equal_range(1);
for (auto iter = vCallbacks.first; iter != vCallbacks.second; iter++) {
    std::function<int(int)> func = iter->second;

    // somehow check function object for context myFoo
    if (func.??? == myFoo)
        // Sorry cant add callback because this object already has registered one
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `myFoo` as the key? or I might have misunderstood the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. You basically cannot inspect the contents of a `std::function` in any useful way.